# Designing XML within InDesign for upload to a database

Tags: xml, database, content-management-system, export, adobe-indesign

Good day all,

I am relatively new to InDesign and XML. I am slowly working through a solution to export my InDesign content as XML and upload it to a Content Management System's Content Database. The content database already has a predefined XML structure for certain elements, which I am trying to follow strictly within InDesign so that the export from InDesign and import into the database will be seamless.

I want to be able to create the entire XML structure within InDesign (Including the content between the tags), but that is where I run into my current issue. I can create the structure using tags just fine, but the content in some of these attributes are not supposed to show on an InDesign page, just in the database, and I don't see an option to create a "Unplaced Text Element" under one of my "value elements.

Example from structure:

item name="CONTENT_ID"

value EnrollmentIntroTxt /value

/item

How do I get the text to show up within the value tags without tagging a text frame on the indesign document? Ideally, I could just type this in.

Comment: You can add non-printing values as attributes and than convert them to values with XSLT during the export.

Answer (score 0):

If the structure is such that you are able to create a text frame and enter the non printing content there, do that and simply delete the frame. The content should remain in the XML tree. Alternatively you could hide the frame.

Of course this technique won't work if you need to enter the XML nodes as elements that are inline with printing content that already has a frame.

Answer (score 0):

You may also consider conditional text.